# How to make a PUT request from a Rails model to controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, sqlite, put

I want to update model via PUT request in Rails app. What would be the best way to do that?

Basically I have:

```
def method
  ...
  @relation = Relation.find(34)
  @relation.name = "new_name"
  @relation.save
end
```

This gives me errors in SQLite ("cannot start a transaction within a transaction").

Switching to put/post should I guess save the problem.. What would be the right way to do it?

Comment: Is this method in a model? I don't see any attempts to make any requests.

Comment: this is a method in a background worker.

Comment: I still don't see how this is related to get/put/post requests.

Comment: Instead of using Relation.save I want to put "new_name" to @relation url, hoping it will help me with transaction within transaction error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some time, I actually found the solution. Here is the code for the Resque worker, that updates the Relation model via PUT. Using this method I don't get SQLite busy exception errors.

```
class VideoCollector
  def self.perform(rel_id)
    @relation = Relation.find_by_id(rel_id)
    @url = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.relation_url(@relation)
    @uri = URI(@url)
    @body ={"collected" => "true"}.to_json
    request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(@uri.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
    request.body = @body
    response = Net::HTTP.new(@uri.host, @uri.port).start {|http| http.request(request) }
  end
end
```

Maybe that will be useful to someone.